# address parsing through inconsisten data

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I am trying to reorganize some bad address values we got from migration and place organized the data with missing values.   The data that we are getting is pretty inconsistent.  some examples as to how the data is retrieved

```
ImportOne: PHILADELPHIA, PA 19103\nUS
ImportTwo:  Artx Street
ImportThree: 19 w 99 St.\nLombard, IL 60148\nUS
ImportFour: El Paso, TX 79922\r\nUS
ImportFive: 6506 Dallerton Street
```

Id like to eventually place the partial data where it belongs as much as I can in a table such as:

```
Id | Address  | City        | State | Zip | Country  |
--- ---------- ------------- ------- ------ -------
1    null       PHILADELPHIA    PA   19103   US      |
-----------------------------------------------------|
2.  Artx Street  null          null   null   null    |
-----------------------------------------------------|
3.  19 w 99 St.   Lombard.     IL.    60148   US     |
-----------------------------------------------------|
4.  null.        El Paso.      TX.    79922.  US     |
-----------------------------------------------------|
```

I tried about parsing the escape characters and splitting it by commas but the data is so inconsistent.  Wondering if anyone has run into this situation?

that about escaping such as this:

```
return str.replace(/\n/g, "\\\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\\\t");
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Fix your database and how your entries are made in the first place. Too many variables.

Comment: @StackSlave too many variables? These is not even some of the more standard ways for storing addresses.   Imagine trying to find out if you have any states that are null?  how do you query that if you have `too` many variables?